# Complex grouping calculation on each date in Matrix Visualization

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am trying to use Power BI Desktop to add some analytic capabilities in my project and need assistance with measuring DAX expression
Here is my data topology

| Country | Status | Year | ConfigId | ByDate | RowNumber | UserId | LastUpdateUtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Pending | 2022 | 1 | 01/012021 | 1 | 1 | 01/01/2021T00:00:00 |

Users with UserId from Country can request report generation with ConfigId for Year
Then report flows Requested -> Pending -> Completed/Failed, it can be done in few days for 1 user
Having a table with provided topology for all users I need to Calculate stats on each day:

1. Reports count rows By Country, Year, Status, ConfigID on each day distict by UserId

So, in general, I need to have a matrix visualization with Country, Year, Status, ConfigID as rows and ByDate as columns, values should be calculated following logic:

1. Set ByDate as a boundary, filter out all records after ByDate
2. Group filtered dataset by Country, UserId, Year, ConfigId and select the top 1 record from each group ordered by LastUpdatedUtc
3. Result of grouping and selecting top 1 record from each group should be grouped a second time by Country, Year, Status, ConfigId and calculate rows count of each group

As a result, measure DAX should return the cumulative state of reports generation history on each day
Column values used as a right boubdary of filter

Issue: in matrix visualization can not find a way to use ByDate Column just like a boundary but not include it in the group by DAX

Please assist if it is possible or suggest please a better solution.

Please help to write correct DAX ot propose different approach